Pointers on paper relating the tail of a binomial distribution to one specific event
My end goal is to find a set of equations to relate $S_r(n)$ to $T_r(n)$, with
$$S_r(n) = \sum_{k=n}^{nr}{ \binom{nr}{k} p^k ( \underbrace{1-p}_{=q} )^{nr-k}}$$
$$T_r(n) = \binom{nr}{n} p^n ( \underbrace{1-p}_{=q} )^{nr-n}$$
I would like to find (an estimate of) the ratio $S_r(n) / T_r(n)$ in as simple a form as possible.  In the paper (listed below) P.J. Brockwell finds a function that consists of a fraction of multivariate polynomials (for coefficients of a polynomial in $1/n$, i.e. $c_0 (1/n)^0 + c_1 (1/n)^1 + c_2 (1/n)^2 + \dots$)

I'm having trouble following the paper
Brockwell, P. J., An asymptotic expansion for the tail of a binomial distribution and its application in queueing theory, J. Appl. Probab. 1, 161-167 (1964). ZBL0131.17003.
which can be accessed for free through JStor:Free Complete Preview.

I can follow most of the document up until page 3, where Equation (6) seems to be pulled out of thin air.
I managed to "solve" the first equation listed by setting
$$\frac{1}{p^{-1}} = \frac{y-1}{y-r}$$
which resulted in
$$y= \frac{p-1}{pr - 1}$$
which is the reciprocal of the first equality in Equation (8).
Beyond that I'm a bit puzzled about how to approach things (I'm actually not even certain that this is correct), and I am really hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.  If someone can provide me with a way of finding the ratios I would be very grateful.
